# Accessing JVM method stack on an unlimited depth

Tags: jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I want to the bytecode transformation using ASM `MethodVisitor`.
My goal it to replace all of the `INVOKEINTERFACE` instructions that call certain methods (they are marked with an annotations) with the following sequence:

```
// instructions that put instance object on stack
INVOKESTATIC package/name/Wrapper wrap (Ljava/lang/Object;)Lpackage/name/Wrapper;
LDC <method_name>
// instructions that put first parameter on stack
INVOKESTATIC package/name/Wrapper wrap (Ljava/lang/Object;)Lpackage/name/Wrapper;
// and so forth for all parameters
INVOKESTATIC package/name/Wrapper invoke (Lpackage/name/Wrapper;<repeat n times>)Lpackage/name/Wrapper;
INVOKESTATIC package/name/Wrapper unwrap (Lpackage/name/Wrapper)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

With one-argument method it is quite easy task. However, things become non-trivial with more arguments, since you can't retrieve stack on any depth. What is the possible solution? Well, first is to back up last `N` stack values in locals, but in this case transformer must be aware of number of used local variables, and therefore the second pass required. Also I don't like how this approach spoils byte code with all these stack back-ups.

The second solution is to build def-use chains and using this information wrap stack values straight after they appear on stack. This approach won't spoil byte code, but several drawbacks exist:

1. First, it is hard to implement.
2. Second, it will require additional pass.
3. Third, def-use chains are expansive to find and keep.
4. Fourth, sometimes it is hard to deal with `DUP` instructions after wrapping, when the dropped value is not to be wrapped either.

One would note that I can use proxying in my case. Unfortunately, I can't, since the transformed byte code will be processed by another transformers/analyzers, that rely on `Wrapper` information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the tree API of ASM. This API allows you to navigate back and forth in the operand stack. This way, you implementation would remain rather simple as you could simply add instructions before you discover the method you want to replace.

Otherwise, you could use ASM's [`LocalVariableSorter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html) when storing your values in the local variable array. At the same time, you would not longer need to worry about overriding later slots. This implementation would execute faster as it would save you from the overhead of the tree API.

I would not worry about performance too much. The JVM's JIT compiler is smart enough to optimize your code once it becomes hot. Either solution should be fine.